# Get the values of a single html table row upon onclick of a button inside the row using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

i have this table and it has a button on its right most column and i wanted that when i click that button, p tags will change according to the values on the row where the button is as of now here is how my table looks like

[image]

and my code

```
<table class="table table-striped table-hover" id="detailTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Record ID</th>
            <th>School Year</th>
            <th>School Quarter</th>
            <th>Student Name</th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>123</td>
                <td>SY 2013-2014</td>
                <td>2nd Quarter</td>
                <td>Billy Joel</td>
                <td><button class="btn" onclick="tgPanel();">Edit</button></td>

            </tr>  
            //more rows here     
    </tbody>
```

and here is my javascript code

```
function tgPanel()
{
   document.getElementById("rid").innerHTML =     document.getElementById("detailTable").rows[0].cells[1].getVal;
   document.getElementById("sy").innerHTML =  document.getElementById("detailTable").rows[0].cells[2].getVal;
   ..and so on..
}
```

Comment: What P tags? where are they? can you please post all relevant HTML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't get any value from your cells using "getVal" use "innerHTML" as well:

> document.getElementById("rid").innerHTML = document.getElementById("detailTable").rows[0].cells[1].innerHTML;

Comment: hi. i change it just as you have said but the value im getting it the header name. is there a way in which the number inside row[0] will change when i click the button on a certain row?

Comment: It would be better to use the *textContent* (or *innerText* for older IE) property than innerHTML.

Comment: use row[0].cells[0].innerHTML = "whatever you want"